# Best way to do a multithread foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a send email method with a foreach, like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   foreach(var user in GetAllUsers())
   {
      SendMail(user.Email);
   }
}
```

I need to improve that method. Using a multithread, because i dont want to wait the SendMail method executes each time for each user.
Any sugestions to do that?
Thanks

Comment: @Polaris878 The problem with "best way" questions is the answer requires context. What if `SendEmail` is coded synchronous? What if `GetAllUsers` ends up locking? The "best way" is constrained to the problem domain of the asker and it's not generally applicable.

Comment: @Polaris878 I agree with your point closing as "too broad" for this question is something we shouldn't do. If we feel broad we could as for more info. but I won't take you point saying "they should not have to google". They need to show effort else question will be closed as "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist"

Comment: If you have an issue with the current status of this question, please take it to [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try using a parallel foreach. I.e.

```
Parallel.ForEach(GetAllUsers(), user=>
{
  SendMail(user.Email);
});
```

Answer (score 13):

You can try something like this

```
private void Send()
{
    Parallel.Foreach(GetAllUsers(), user => 
    {
       SendMail(user.Email);
    });
}
```

Comment: You can limit the threads by using parameter: MaxDegreeOfParallelism

Comment: You answered in parallel with Mike!

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way to do this would be thread pooling. .Net makes this pretty easy and you can read more about it [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as.aspx)