# Processing files in multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a windows form application which loads a list of paths to video files into an array, and then with a `foreach (string[] file in fileList)` loop, will go through each file and run some analysis of the video file, then write the result back to the filelist array.

The trouble is that it processes each video file at slightly less than real time which is not idea. I am aiming to split up the task across multiple threads. I have tested opening the application 5 times and ran the processing on separate files. The CPU handles this without issue.

What would be the simplest way to split up the processing across multiple threads?

Edit: I am new to multi threading, and currently learning. I know there are different ways to multi-thread but I am looking for the method I should be using in order to learn about it.

I found this example, however I don't understand how it works, it seems too simple compared to other examples I have been looking at.
[Best way to do a multithread foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541046/best-way-to-do-a-multithread-foreach-loop)

Comment: `Parallel.For` and `Parallel.ForEach` are easy to use - let us be glad about this. What is your actual question ?

Comment: @rboe How to I change this: `foreach (string[] file in fileList)` to use `Parallel.ForEach` ?

Comment: Also, does this mean that it will process every file at the same time? I would rather process 5 max at a time. I have worked out how to do this now, although now I'm getting Access Violation Exception errors. Each loop should be using a separate file.

Comment: Start by reading up on the very basics of Parallel.For* .

Comment: And processing files is not the best candidate for Parallel.

Comment: I understand better now about using Parallel.ForEach. The "processing" is a complex motion detection algorithm where results are currently written back to a ListView.

Comment: Off topic, but is there a stackoverflow backed way to pay someone to do this? Freelancer scares me with desperate people!

Answer (score 1):

If the results are added to the same collection, PLINQ makes it a bit easier:

```
var results = fileList.AsParallel().Select(file => {
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
    var result = bytes.Length;
    return result;
}).ToList();
```